# Rows as dictionaries - pymssql

Tags: python, dictionary, pymssql

I want to receive rows as dictionaries in pymssql. in python-idle i ran:

```
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(host='192.168.1.3', user='majid', password='123456789', database='GeneralTrafficMonitor', as_dict=True)
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.tblTrafficCounterData')
>>> cur.as_dict
True
>>> for row in cur:
    print row['ID']
```

But it gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 2, in <module>
    print row['ID']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Could someone help?

Comment: Maybe __iter__() was leftover by as_dict support, try the same with for row in cur.fetchall() as the documentation is explicit that fetchall() supports as_dict. That sounds a little stupid but you never know ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the version of pymssql that you are using. Only [since 1.0.2](http://pymssql.sourceforge.net/examples_pymssql.php) does it return a dict, earlier versions seem to return tuple.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the parameter as_dict=True like so:

```
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
```

You will then be able to access row['id'] if it is a field name in the result set.

As per documentation below:

https://pythonhosted.org/pymssql/pymssql_examples.html#rows-as-dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set as_dict=True while creating the connection itself.

```
pymssql.connect(server='.', user='', password='', database='', as_dict=True,)
```

https://pythonhosted.org/pymssql/ref/pymssql.html?highlight=connect#pymssql.connect

Answer (score 0):

Specifying results as dictionaries can be done on a cursor by cursor basis:

```py
import pymysql
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor

# create database connection
# connect to database
mydb = pymysql.connect( ... )

mycursor = mydb.cursor(cursor=DictCursor)
```